# If-statement in a Variable

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I want to print the same page's name differently based on a certain variable.

Here is a corresponding code.

```
$metaTitle ="'if($variable=='input'){ title#1 }else {  title#2 };'";
```

And the produced meta title is lately used in the same file to create the page title (`<title></title>`)

But it keeps producing the title like

```
if($variable=='input'){ title#1 }else {  title#2 };
```

(the whole if statement as a whole. It does not recognize the if statement. It considers the statement as a plain text.)

What did I do wrong in the sentence??

Comment: it really helps us if you tag your question with the language you're using.

Comment: It's PHP. Sorry, but it's resolved! Thanks for the notification :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you just assign $metaTitle a STRING "'if($variable=='input'){ title#1 }else { title#2 };'" and it's not a runable statement

you should do like this

```
if ($variable=='input') {
    $metaTitle = "title#1";
} else {
    $metaTitle = "title#2";
}
```

or simply use Ternary Operator

Answer (score 16):

Use ternary operator "?:":

```
$metaTitle = ($variable=='input')? "title#1" : "title#2";
```

The first part is the condition:

```
($variable=='input')
```

The second is the result when condition is true:

```
"title#1"
```

The third is the result when condition is false:

```
"title#2"
```

Source http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most basic solution is to set the title variable inside the if statement.

```
if($variable=='input'){
  $metaTitle = 'title#1';
} else {
  $metaTitle = 'title#2';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead -

```
if($variable=='input')
{ 
   $metaTitle = 'title#1'; 
}
else 
{ 
  $metaTitle = 'title#2'; 
}
```